# 3 random numbers from 2 random numbers task

Tags: math, probability, probability-theory

Suppose, you have some uniform destribution **rnd(x)** function what will return 0 or 1.
How you can use this function to create any **rnd(x,n)** function what will return uniform distributed numbers from 0 to n?

I mean everyone using it, but for me it's not so clever. For example, I can create distributions with right border 2^n-1 ([0-1],[0-3],[0-7], etc.) but can't find a way how to do this for ranges like [0-2] or [0-5] without using very big numbers for reasonable precision.

Comment: Check arithmetic coding; basically AC treats the input as a very big number, but each code word can be decoded from a reasonably small neighborhood of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you need to create function `rnd(n)` which returns uniformly distributed random number in range [0, n] by using another function `rnd1()` which returns 0 or 1.

1. Find such smallest `k` that `2^k >= n+1`
2. Create number consisting of `k` bits and fill all its bits by using `rnd1()`. Result is uniformly distributed number in range [0, 2^k-1]
3. Compare generated number to `n`. If it is smaller or equal to n, return it. Otherwise go to step 2.

In general, this is a variation of how to generate uniform numbers in small range by using library function which generates numbers in large range:

```
unsigned int rnd(n) {
  while (true) {
    unsigned int x = rnd_full_unsigned_int();
    if (x < MAX_UNSIGNED_INT / (n+1) * (n+1)) {
      return x % (n+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation for above code. If you simply return `rnd_full_unsigned_int() % (n+1)` then this will generate bias towards small valued numbers. Black spiral represents all possible values from 0 to MAX_UNSIGNED_INT, counted from inside. Length of single revolution path is (n+1). Red line shows why bias occurs. So, in order to remove this bias we first create random number x in range [0, MAX_UNSIGNED_INT] (this is easy with bit-fill). Then, if x falls into bias-generating region, we recreate it. We keep recreating it until it doesn't fall into bias-generating region. x at this moment is in form `a*(n+1)-1`, so `x % (n+1)` is a uniformly distributed number [0, n]. 
[image]

Comment: Im not sure that the result will be uniformly distributed. Can you explain why is it so? I will really apreciate that.

Comment: The random number is uniform in the range 0..2^k-1, so it's also uniform in any subrange, e.g. [m .. 2^k - n]; the disadvantage is that when 'n' or 'm' is large, one has to discard many (all) bits of random data.

Comment: Thanks, now I see how it is! By the way is there a way to do this more efficiently? I mean, possibility of failure is 1-n/(2^ceil(log2(n))) and some times can be almost 50%.